# is passing argument a viewmodel or a protocol

Tags: swift, struct, swift2, swift-protocols

The codes are taken from [Protocol Oriented MVVM](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-2-0-protocol-oriented-mvvm/) and this is how `ViewModel` looks like :

```
struct MinionModeViewModel: SwitchWithTextCellDataSource {
    var title = "Minion Mode!!!"
    var switchOn = true
}

extension MinionModeViewModel: SwitchWithTextCellDelegate {
    func onSwitchTogleOn(on: Bool) {
        if on {
            print("The Minions are here to stay!")
        } else {
            print("The Minions went out to play!")
        }
    }
    
    var switchColor: UIColor {
        return .yellowColor()
    }
}
```

I understand this part. Basically, `MinionModeViewModel`  are overriding some default behaviors of `SwitchWithTextCellDelegate` and  `SwitchWithTextCellDelegate`

Next the author is configuring the cell by passing `viewModel` as arguments :

```
SettingsViewController.swift

let viewModel = MinionModeViewModel()
cell.configure(withDataSource: viewModel, delegate: viewModel)
return cell
```

However, at `SwitchWithTextTableViewCell`, the arguments of `configure` method are `SwitchWithTextCellDataSource` and `SwitchWithTextCellDelegate`

```
func configure(withDataSource dataSource: SwitchWithTextCellDataSource, delegate: SwitchWithTextCellDelegate?) {
        self.dataSource = dataSource
        self.delegate = delegate
        
        label.text = dataSource.title
        switchToggle.on = dataSource.switchOn
        // color option added!
        switchToggle.onTintColor = delegate?.switchColor
    }
```

Im new to Swift. Can someone please explain

1. what are the names and their meaning `dataSource` and `delegate` of the `configure`method in `SwitchWithTextTableViewCell` . Are they `External Parameter Names`.
2. why the type of passing arguments of `configure` method are different : `view model` vs `protocols` types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all MinionModeViewModel is not overriding the default behaviours of SwitchWithTextCellDelegate and  SwitchWithTextCellDelegate.

The term overriding is used along with the inheritance. 
Example

```
class A {
  func someFunction() {
  }
}
class B:A {
  override func someFunction() {
  }
}
```

Here class B is subclass of class A and thus if class B should provide different implementation of method someFunction than its class A it should override it and provide different implementation.

Protocols are different. It's kind of abstract class. Protocols are just set of rules.
So when some class or struct conforms to a protocol it means that they should implement all the required methods or properties stated in the protocol definition.

Example:

```
protocol SwitchWithTextCellDelegate {

  func onSwitchTogleOn(on: Bool)

  var switchColor: UIColor {get}
}
```

Now any structs or class that conforms to protocol SwitchWithTextCellDelegate should implement onSwitchToggleOn method and also should have a property switchColor which will have a getter.

Like you have done:

```
extension MinionModeViewModel: SwitchWithTextCellDelegate {
    func onSwitchTogleOn(on: Bool) {
    }

    var switchColor: UIColor {
        return someColor
    }
}
```

**Explanation for the method**

```
1. func configure(withDataSource dataSource: SwitchWithTextCellDataSource, delegate: SwitchWithTextCellDelegate?)
```

**dataSource**: In this parameter we can pass any class or struct that conforms to protocol SwitchWithTextCellDataSource protcol

**delegate**: In this parameter we can pass any class or struct that conforms to protocol SwitchWithTextCellDelegate

Now it might be confusing that the author of the tutorial has passed same object in both parameter. Why not pass it as a single parameter?

```
let viewModel = MinionModeViewModel()
cell.configure(withDataSource: viewModel, delegate: viewModel)
```

It's because here MinionModeViewModel is conforming to both  SwitchWithTextCellDataSource and SwitchWithTextCellDelegate protocol so we can pass same object in both parameter. But this method has the flexibility to pass any object that conforms to those protocols.

Answer (score 1):

Protocols define behavior that adopting objects implement (they are not overwriting behaviors - usually).

In this example, `SwitchWithTextCellDataSource` and `SwitchWithTextCellDelegates` are `protocols` that the `MinionModelViewModel` inherited (adopted).  For this to make more sense, consider you might have another struct:

```
struct EvilVillanViewModel: SwitchWithTextCellDataSource {
  var title: "Evil Villian Model!!!"
  var switchOn = false
}
```

Since this struct also adopts `SwitchWithTextCellDataSource`, it is interchangeable anywhere code would be expecting an `class`/`struct` that implements `SwitchWithTextCellDataSource` - because it knows that it will have a title, and a switchOn value - because the protocol demands it.  Your code will not compile without it.

So....in `configure(withDataSource dataSource: SwitchWithTextCellDataSource...)`, you could just as easily pass in an `EvilVillanViewModel` struct or a `MinionModelViewModel` and everything will work perfectly.  When the code block references `dataSource.title`, it knows whatever you passed it has a `title`, because it had to conform to the `SwitchWithTextCellDataSource` protocol.

And that is just the very beginning of the power of protocols!  Hope this helps!